# PayPal Return Variable is Changing the URL I have set for this

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I don't know if this matters, but I'm in Sandbox mode, and the Return URL, I have set to:

`http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=testing;sa=thankyou`

But when I make a purchase, it sends me to:

`http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=testing%3bsa%3dthankyou&tx=7T076948J4774772C&st=Completed&amt=100%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=`

How do I make it go to `http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=testing;sa=thankyou` instead?

Also, I already have `rm=2` in the variables, but it is still changing the URL.  Haven't tested this in the actual live site yet, just the sandbox.  But am concerned that this is going to happen in the live PayPal site also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have PDT enabled in the account receiving the payment? If you do, the return method to your site would always be a GET and that would override what you have set in your `return` URL.

Comment: How can you tell if PDT is enabled or not?  Not seeing that anywhere.  I have IPN enabled, but this is important to have enabled for the `notify_url`  But is it possible to have PDT Disabled and IPN Still enabled?

Comment: Ok, YES, PDT is enabled!  But will IPN still work with PDT Disabled?

Comment: Ok, so I disabled PDT, I just hope it doesn't prevent IPN notifications being sent to the IPN Listener, which updates my database and sends out an electronic download file...  So we'll see.

Comment: PDT and IPN are two different things. If you  define a notification URL in the button code or have the feature enabled in your account you'll be good to go. If you had to pick one feature to use it should be IPN. With PDT you only get details when a buyer returns to your site - which doesn't always happen. If you're using Subscriptions you would get an IPN post for the creation, payment, and expiration of the subscription with PDT you would get nothing.